# Magento 2 How can i Change Sortorder in fornted order_view.xml in order_total

Tags: magento2, blocks, sales-order, sorting, custom-field

I want to change sorting order in order_total block in frontend order view page.

[image]

can any one tell me how i can change sorting order.

Comment: In this question do you want Shipping AV and ST to move up as well.

Comment: yes i want to move up both. i write that cod in sales_order_view.xml in fronted layout.